# Emulator Building in Landscape Mode Always?

Tags: android, android-emulator

Can anyone please guide why i am getting landscape mode in following configuration :

API 11, MDPI

[config]

```
avd.ini.encoding=ISO-8859-1
hw.dPad=no
hw.lcd.density=160
hw.cpu.arch=arm
hw.device.hash=1473123938
hw.camera.back=none
disk.dataPartition.size=200M
skin.path=320x480
skin.dynamic=yes
hw.keyboard.lid=yes
hw.keyboard=yes
hw.ramSize=512
hw.device.manufacturer=Generic
hw.sdCard=no
hw.mainKeys=yes
hw.accelerometer=yes
skin.name=320x480
abi.type=armeabi
hw.trackBall=no
hw.device.name=3.2in HVGA slider (ADP1)
hw.battery=yes
hw.sensors.proximity=yes
image.sysdir.1=platforms\android-11\images\
hw.sensors.orientation=yes
hw.audioInput=yes
hw.gps=yes
vm.heapSize=16
```

Comment: I don't see your configuration!!

Comment: you are not able to see the picture??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of the model name of the device you're using. It's always in landscape mode when the keyboard is open.  ;)

```
hw.keyboard.lid=yes
hw.keyboard=yes
hw.device.name=3.2in HVGA slider (ADP1)
```

[image]

Comment: I want to use 3.0 with mdpi, which model name should i use then.

Comment: That's the second problem. Android 3.0 was especially made for tablets, not phones, and tablets tend to default to landscape mode.

Comment: thats the reason and slap for downvoters. Salut for you Stephan, Many many thanks for guiding. I am updating the API version in question . please update your answer.

Comment: Also, mdpi is a low resolution for a phone nowadays, and it's more likely to be found on tablets especially, or on older/cheaper phones. So if you want to target older phone or cheaper phones, you may want to test it on Android 2.3. And yes, there are still brand new phones being made with Gingerbread 2.3, because of the lower end hardware requirements of those devices. Also, you should check out http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html (Ideally, if you're just an independent developer with limited resources, you should try to test for the most common configurations).

Comment: By the way, I forgot to say. I'm not 100% sure, because devices like the Xoom have an explicit default orientation of landscape, but with this slider model, you may be able to get it to show in portrait mode if you say 'no' to the keyboard or 'no' to the keyboard lid in your configuration.